# QGIS filter a 'value relation' to show only intersecting features

Tags: qgis, valuerelation

I am trying to model the 'splicing' of cables (Table 1) together at a splice point (Table 2).

- Table 1 - "Cables" (linestring)
- Table 2 - "Nodes" (point)
- Table 3 - "splices" (geomless table with int fields for ID of "Nodes", and "Cables" a&b)

I have created the third table ("splices") to do this by using a value relation to both Nodes & Cables ('a' & 'b' for the two ends of the cable).

When creating a new record in "splices", once "Node" is selected I would like to only return nearby "Cables".

[image]

To filter the Cables I have used:

`intersects($geometry, buffer(geometry(get_feature_by_id('[qgis node layer]','7067')), 0.000005))`

This works, but as you can see, I am referring to Node id (7067) statically. How can I instead use the Node id of the selected Node?

I wondered if I need to use `current_parent_value(field_name)` to find the Node id, but can't seem to make that work.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `current_value('field_name')` to access the unsaved value of `field_name` in the current form. In this case, it's the node id.

Adapt the following expression in your splice layer Value Relation widget under Filter Expression for both Cable A and Cable B fields:

```
intersects($geometry,
    buffer(geometry(get_feature('node_layer','node_id',current_value('node'))),0.5))
```

Or, if you want the Cable B field to automatically bring up the Cable B value based on the Cable A value, use the above expression for Cable A, and the following one for Cable B - preferably make it read only if you want to avoid accidentally changing it.

`"cable_a_id" = current_value('cable_a')`

---

Demonstration of using the first expression for Cable A and second expression for Cable B.

[image]
Widget settings in splice layer for Cable A field

[image]
Widget settings in splice layer for Cable B field

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer, that works perfectly :)

Comment: Glad to have helped and thank you for accepting the answer!