# QGIS - Value relation values based on geometry

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, relation

I am having a problem with last part of defining values in geopackage.

I have created relation values based on field values (drop-down values). Last one I want to create, is to make relation based on geometry (intersection with another layer).

I have points layer (imeGC as field I want to be populated), and polygon layer gc (with imeGC as field I want to use values to populate point layer).

So, when I add new point, I want to imeGC field to automatically be populated with values from gc polygon layer, when the point is within (intersects) that layer.

[image]

I tried with variations from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419242/qgis-filter-a-value-relation-to-show-only-intersecting-features), but with no luck. I used variation of this code.

```
intersects($geometry, buffer(geometry(get_feature('node_layer','node_id',current_value('node'))),0.5))
```

EDIT: I will replicate this also with line layer (Roads), so the code should be applicable to that also.

EDIT 2: The only answer which is near my wanted solution is this code:

```
array_first(overlay_nearest('LAYER_B',"FIELD_OF_LAYER_B", limit:=1, max_distance:=2))
```

But with this code, I get the wanted value in brackets:

```
(NameOfStreet)
```

My next questions are, how to get a value without brackets, and how to limit the results to 3 nearest?

Comment: If you use QGIS 3.16+ you can use `overlay_intersects()`.

Comment: I tried that, but I do not know how to integrate it with buffer. It works with polygons, but not with lines, when I need buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Just extract the first array element, e.g. using *bracket notation*:

```
overlay_nearest( 'LAYER_B',"FIELD_OF_LAYER_B" )[0]
```

*See the expression description for additional filter and ordering options.*

Not sure what you intend to do with the 3 *nearest neighbors*, but you can add `limit:=3` to have the engine retrieve the `FIELD_OF_LAYER_B` values from the 3 nearest features of each layer in order.

---

While this expression is favorable for lines, it is likely unwanted for when *intersection* with a polygon is a required predicate.
Now, you can (and probably want to) add a `max_distance` value to the above expression to find candidates only in the given proximity (much like with a buffer) for both layers, or just define a different expression for the polygon layer:

```
overlay_intersects( 'LAYER_B',"FIELD_OF_LAYER_B" )[0]
```